# Reuse last time step as initial condition in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am using the code below to simulate a PDE and then reuse the last "X-slice" as an initial condition for another simulation. Here by "X-slice" I mean keeping t fixed at t = 10 and running through the X values.

```
eq = {D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 1}] == x^2 Cos[x], 
u[0, x] == x^2, u[t, -5] == u[t, 5]};

sol = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -5, 5}, MaxStepSize -> 0.14];

eq2 = {D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 1}] == x^2 Cos[x], 
u[0, x] == u[10, x] /. sol, u[t, -5] == u[t, 5]};
sol2 = NDSolve[eq2, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -5, 5}, MaxStepSize -> 0.14];
```

The first simulation runs but then I get the following error:

> NDSolve::ndode: The equations {<<1>>} are not differential equations
>   or initial conditions in the dependent variables {u}.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's a matter of precedence: The `/. sol` in the IC of `eq2` replaces both instances of `u`.  Instead parenthesize thus: `u[0, x] == (u[10, x] /. First@sol)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change one of the `u` and replace it with another name, say `u1`.

```
mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf : False | True, sf_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {tf, "ScaleFactor" -> sf}}

eq = {D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 1}] == x^2 Cos[x], 
   u[0, x] == x^2, u[t, -5] == u[t, 5]};

sol = NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -5, 5}, Method -> Union[mol[70, 4], mol[True, 100]]];

Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.8]], 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
eq2 = {D[u1[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u1[t, x], {x, 1}] == x^2 Cos[x], 
   u1[0, x] == u[10, x] /. sol, u1[t, -5] == u1[t, 5]};
sol2 = NDSolve[eq2, u1, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -5, 5}, 
   Method -> Union[mol[70, 4], mol[True, 100]]];

Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[t, x] /. sol2], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.8]], 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]